# How can I check whether my child process is ended in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, multiprocessing, procfs

I am new to multi-processing in C. I am using `fork` to create a child process.
Now I want to check if my child has ended(So I can continue to the next step).

I tried to check whether `/proc/${my child pid}/` exsits, but I realise that not until I call `waitpid`, it will exsit as zombie forever.

Here is some code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int child() {
    sleep(5); // do some work here, cost a few seconds.
    return 0;
}

bool check_if_child_died(int id) {
    // how to complete this function?
}

int main() {
    printf("BEFORE\n");
    int id = fork();
    if (id == -1) { return -1; }

    if (id != 0) {
        // father.
        printf("FATHER STARTED.\n");
    } else {
        // child
        child();
        printf("CHILD END.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while (true) {
        if (check_if_child_died(id)) {
            printf("CHILD ENDED!\n");
            break;
        }

        sleep(1); // some other work costs time here.
    }

    printf("END.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to already know about `waitpid` so it's not clear why you don't just use that. `waitpid` can be used to wait for a process to exit or to check whether the process has exited.

Comment: @kaylum Would you please explain a bit more? It seems waitpid block my process until the child ended. But I wants to check it in a non-blocking way.

Comment: Check `options` param of `waitpid()`

Comment: Please read the [waitpid manual](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid). The `WNOHANG` options flag can be used to not block.

Comment: Your understanding of fork return seems to be switched.